# Where in Mac OS are Shockwave plugins stored?

Tags: macos, adobe

I don't think I even have a Shockwave plugin, unless it came with the browser.  But if I do, I want to remove it and/or check the version number.  IDS detected a CVE-2010-3655 attack aimed at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-view-and-remove-safari-plug-ins-2260895

Safari-->Help-->Installed Plugins

Answer (score 1):

Browser plug-ins are generally installed in either:

- /Library/Internet Plug-Ins
- ~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins

and can just be deleted from there. OS X itself will also sometimes move incompatible plug-ins to a 'Disabled Plug-Ins' sub-folder, and you can do that too if you're not ready to completely discard them. (Though in that case, you might as well use Safari's Security Preferences to temporarily disable them.)